# How to monitor window or document events registered by HighCharts

Tags: highcharts, salesforce

I am developing an application using **Salesforce1 Lightning Component Framework**. I have used HighCharts to display some data in graphical format. While submitted for security review for AppExchange Publishing, the HighCharts resource script file was flagged to be having security issues.

**Comment from security review team:**

> "These libraries register event handlers and modify the DOM outside of
>   the lightning renderer lifecycle. This can cause undefined behavior
>   and breaks security policy."

When asked about this issue a suggestion given from security team is to unregister all events added by the HighCharts in unrender(). Any suggestion on possible ways to find out the registered window or document events would be much appreciated.

Note: All HighCharts invocation is done from Renderer only.